# cryptsetup luksOpen vs cryptsetup open

Tags: cryptsetup

Just wanted to confirm whether my suspicion is correct or not, that is to say, are these two identical in function and the context in which they are used?

- cryptsetup luksOpen
- cryptsetup open

I couldn't see anything specific in the man page referring to 'cryptsetup open'. I see in various places (example: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Device_encryption) that both commands appear.

Do they have nuances in how they are used, or are they completely interchangeable?

Comment: In the [manual page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cryptsetup.8.html#BASIC_COMMANDS), luksOpen is an alias to `open --type luks`.

Comment: Gah, sorry, I'd apparently skipped straight past those alias at the top to the argument section for luksOpen. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Quasimodo for the pointer. This is indeed an alias (there are others also). I presume at this stage (mid 2020), that the default option for 'open' is '--type luks' when it isn't specified (as opposed to luks2), or else there is some sort of automatic identification of the type...

Source: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cryptsetup.8.html#BASIC_COMMANDS

> For backward compatibility there are open command aliases:
>
> ```
>           luksOpen: open --type luks
> ```

It also notes that luksOpen is the old syntax:

> open --type luks
>
> ```
>    luksOpen <device> <name> (old syntax)
> ```